# OpenCL on Ventura/how to speed up whisper.cpp on an Intel-Mac with Radeon GPU?

Tags: performance, intel, opencl, macos

I use [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/) a lot and recent updates has added support for [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/api/opencl) using [CLBlast](https://github.com/CNugteren/CLBlast), https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp#opencl-gpu-support-via-clblast but according to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254008829 OpenCL seems to be deprecated in recent versions of MacOS.

Deprecated often means that it is still available but not recommended to use because it is gonna disappear in the future. Since I want to use it here and now I don't care about what happens in the future but when I try to compile it I get an error message about missing OpenCL-libraries:

```
% WHISPER_CLBLAST=1 make -j
(a lot of debug info deleted)
c++ -I. -I./examples -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -fPIC -pthread examples/quantize/quantize.cpp examples/common.cpp examples/common-ggml.cpp ggml.o ggml-opencl.o whisper.o -o quantize -L/opt/local/lib/ -framework Accelerate -lclblast -lOpenCL
ld: library not found for -lOpenCL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bench] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ld: library not found for -lOpenCL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [quantize] Error 1
ld: library not found for -lOpenCL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

However, when I search for OpenCL I find it in the different XCode SDKs for MacOS development.

Does Ventura still include OpenCL? If yes, how can I use it with whisper.cpp? If no, are there other ways to speedup whisper.cpp on an Intel Mac with a Radeon GPU?